# Why input redirection works by default for sudo and not for passwd? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, linux, f#, stdin

Simple F# script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fsharpi

open System
open System.Diagnostics

let Exec (command: string, arguments: string, echo: bool) =
    let psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(command)

    psi.Arguments <- arguments
    psi.UseShellExecute <- false
    if (echo) then
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", command, arguments)
    let p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
    p.WaitForExit()
    p.ExitCode

Exec("sudo", "-k ls -lha /root", true)
Exec("passwd", "myusername", true)
```

*(But actually this is a generic ".NET on Linux" question I guess, because you could write the same in C#)*

Why the first Exec() call works and the second one doesn't?

The first one calls sudo properly, and sudo asks me for my password (I can even fail to type it, and it asks it to me again, so it's not related to number of carrier returns employed in *stdin*).

However, the second one only allows me to write one character and suddenly drops out. It seems to not redirect characters to `passwd` properly, as the latter doesn't let me write the complete password, and fails saying that passwords don't match.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `passwd` usually doesn't use standard I/O (mostly for security reasons). You can check the man page for your `passwd` to see if there's an option to enable stdio - e.g. `passwd --stdin`. If not, you'll need to use a different utility, like `chpasswd`.

All in all, nothing to do with .NET. You couldn't do the same thing from your shell either :) Passwords aren't for applications or scripts - they're for users.

Comment: how can `passwd` gather the password at all if it's not from stdin?

Comment: @knocte Directly from the terminal. Don't forget, the standard input stream is just a stream of text - there's no way you could use that for things like masked or hidden input, just like there's no positioning of text cursor in standard output. It's the same on Windows - the difference between using just `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.CursorTop`, for example :) If you see a console application that does anything more complicated than "add another character to the output stream", you know it's not using stdio.